# how can we execute a plan via motion planning interface in moveit?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when we use movegroup interface we can execute a plan using

```
move_group.move();
```

and in python movegroup intertace we use:

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)
plan = group.go(wait=True)
group.execute(plan, wait=True).
```

how about when we use motion planning interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310827/how-can-we-execute-a-plan-via-motion-planning-interface-in-moveit?/) by [MahShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/37854/mahshah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Motion Planning API tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/motion_planning_api/motion_planning_api_tutorial.html) does not answer this, because it stops at visualizing the trajectory.

As commented in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/305963/followjointtrajectoryaction-feasibility-checking/), you can still use the move_group's `execute` function with your own plan, for example like this:

```
// [(continued from the tutorial)...]  
context->solve(res); 
moveit_msgs::MotionPlanResponse response; 
res.getMessage(response); 

// Construct a move_group plan from the planned trajectory
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan myplan;
myplan.trajectory_ = response.trajectory; 
group.execute(myplan);
```

Otherwise, my understanding is that you can use the interface of your robot/motors, most commonly a `JointTrajectoryController` advertising a `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` that you send your trajectory to.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/37854/mahshah/) on 2019-02-15**:
that is right, thank you

**Comment by [ddl_hust](https://answers.ros.org/users/41049/ddl_hust/) on 2019-04-25**:
thank you help me lots!